# Where should I specify key for a route in 'react-navigation'?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using 'react-navigation'. The documentation provides several methods to update params based on key, or go back to previous screen based on key. However, it does not specify where we specify the key for a route.

Is the key automatically configured? Or is it manually specified in the route definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys are auto generated. For the `TabNavigator`, the keys are the tab names, and for `StackNavigator` it's usually just some random id.

To use it, you can read the navigation state from `this.props.navigation.state` and store it for later use.